# ASP Identity GenerateUserTokenAsync(string purpose, TKey userId) purpose options

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

So a UserManager has a function called GenerateUserTokenAsync(string purpose, TKey userId).

What does this do in ASP Identity? Can I use this to generate OAuth Bearer tokens? Also what is the purpose parameter for? What values can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for 'GenerateUserTokenAsync' says

> Get a user token for a specific purpose

These methods should be used for generating a custom or specific reset token using a custom provider that inherits DataProtectorTokenProvider
(`GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync`)  (`GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`).

Usage with Confirmation and ResetPassword built in provider:

```
GenerateUserTokenAsync("Confirmation", userId); // email confirmation

GenerateUserTokenAsync("ResetPassword", userId); // password reset
```

In default implementation of token provider (`TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider`) purpose is used as some sort of password in cryptographic token generation.

Normally, you don't need to call `GenerateUserTokenAsync` directly unless you have a specific use case like a custom username change flow that you want to implement a reset token for. Otherwise just call `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` or `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`.

Comment: The reason its public is that applications are free to use the API to generate tokens for their own purposes.  If an app wanted to generate change username tokens using this api, they could do directly use the Generate/Validate methods with a custom purpose like ("ChangeName")

Comment: how to provide token provider?

Answer (score 10):

```
UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(User, TokenProvider, Purpose)
```

can be used to generate Tokens for purposes that are not implemented be the UserManager.

One example could be an invitation system. In a WebProject you need to create a TokenProvider like this:

```
public class InvitationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public InvitationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, IOptions<InvitationTokenProviderOptions> options, ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger) : base(dataProtectionProvider, options, logger)
    {

    }
}
```

and the InvitationTokenProviderOptions

```
public class InvitationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
}
```

then you can register it in `StartUp.ConfigureServices()`.

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
{
    // ...
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContect>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   .AddTokenProvider<InvitationTokenProvider<User>>("Invitation");
```

Afterwards you can use it with the UserManger like this

```
// create a token    
string token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "Invitation", "Invitation");
// verify it
bool result = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, "Invitation", "Invitation", token);
```

If you are going to use the token in URLs, don't forget to make it URL-Safe (it may contain '/' and other symbols.
Also check if trailing '==' is lost on the way through emails and browsers.

Comment: my verification result always returns false. I'm encoding the token and then decoding it using HttpUtility. Any ideas why this might be the case?
```cs
var invitationToken = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "invitation", "invitation");
var _invitationToken = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(invitationToken);

//verify
var authorized = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(dbUser,"invitation","invitation",                                                                          HttpUtility.UrlDecode(invitationToken));
```

Comment: first i'd use the debugger to copy the token to a text editor when its generated (before UrlEncode) and then again just before you try to validate it (after UrlDecode). that way i found that my emailservice seems to remove trailing '=='.

Comment: thanks for your response. Turns out it's an issue with Angular when I send the token to my Api.